# ints objc always null

Tags: objective-c

I have `int control;` in the .h

I have tried everything in the .m

```
control =0; or 1,2,3 etc
int control =0; or 1,2,3 etc
control ++;
control=control +1;
```

No matter what, it is nill when I use NSLog. I have never experienced anything like this in four languages.

Comment: Please show an example of your use of `NSLog()`.

Comment: `int` values could not possibly be `nil` - you are probably using a wrong format specifier (i.e. not a `%d`).

Comment: We need to see your exact, real code. Your description "`int control;` in the .h" could mean at least two things, each of which has very different implications.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably using `NSLog(@"%@", control)` instead of `NSLog(@"%d", control)`.

`NSLog` requires the use of a format string, which you can read more about [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html). It does not allow you to directly log variables, you *must* place variables within a format string and follow them with a comma-separated listed.

Comment: I'm betting he's doing NSLog(control), and the other four languages are all scripting languages. ;)